# Can not install mysql-server-5.7 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, package-management, apt

I want to install `mysql-server` on my Ubuntu machine with

`sudo apt install mysql-server` but the installation fails with this error

```
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.26, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You might have dependencies problem, with a package that is only partially installed. Try doing `apt-get --purge remove` before the install.

Comment: "Is not configured yet" could mean that the previous attempt to install it failed, but without a transcript of that, we can't tell you anything more.